# In a visualvm heap dump, what is the number after "Local Variable" for threads?

Tags: java, visualvm, heap-dump

I am analyzing the threads in the heap dump using the `VisualVM` and am wondering whats the count after the `Local Variable: byte[]` in the below thread means? does it mean the size of the variable? or the total number of instances of the variable? or anything else?

```
"Multicast Heartbeat Receiver Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=38 RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(<unknown string>)
       Local Variable: java.util.zip.ZStreamRef#366
       Local Variable: java.util.zip.Inflater#366
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(<unknown string>)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(<unknown string>)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.PayloadUtil.ungzip(PayloadUtil.java:194)
       Local Variable: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream#1
       Local Variable: byte[]#537427
       Local Variable: byte[]#537474
       Local Variable: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream#317
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver$MulticastReceiverThread.processPayload(MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver.java:142)
       Local Variable: org.glowroot.agent.model.TraceEntryImpl#12145
       Local Variable: org.glowroot.agent.model.OptionalThreadContextImpl#7
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver$MulticastReceiverThread.run(MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver.java:126)
       Local Variable: byte[]#4513
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number after the `#` is a sequence number. E.g. `Local Variable: byte[]#537427` means that this is your 537427:th instance of `byte[]`.

It becomes clear if you click the `instances` tab in visual vm. In the following picture I see a list of all my byte arrays in my test program, enumerated from `#1` and onwards, where *N items* denotes the size of the array.

[image]